# Lift of chain complex diagram with acyclicity

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I'm trying to prove that given a morphism of chain complexes $p : X \rightarrow Y$ where all the $p_n : X_n \rightarrow Y_n$ are surjective, one has a lift

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> X\\
@VVV @V{p}VV \\
C @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$

where $C$ is acyclic ( $C_n$ is projective for all $n$ and $C_n = 0$ for $n \ll 0$ )

Any solution would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming only that $C$ is degree-wise projective and bounded to the right, or also that it is *acyclic*? Note that the last hypothesis is not needed if $p$ is also a quasi-isomorphism, but I would not call such a complex acyclic, but rather cofibrant. If you do not assume that $p$ is a quasi-isomorphism, then you do want $C$ to be acyclic.